# PayPal subscription button error please return to merchant and choose another way to pay

Tags: javascript, paypal

So, I integrated a PayPal subscription button in the website I'm making with node and express and it's still running in localhost, I used the sandbox test and it worked but when I go live it doesn't work, and when I try to login in with a live account and pay I get this error message:

Sorry, we weren’t able to set up preapproved payments at this time.
Please return to the merchant and choose another way to pay.

Why is this happening? is it because of some security measure because I'm running it in a website that doesn't have an SSL certificate "localhost" or some other thing I should add to the code or what?

PayPal Javascript code:

```
paypal.Buttons({
          style: {
            shape: 'pill',
            color: 'blue',
            layout: 'horizontal',
            label: 'paypal', 
          },
          createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.subscription.create({
              'plan_id': 'P-xxxxxx'
            });
          },
          onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            alert(data.subscriptionID);
          },
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you received that message in live mode, testing with a live account, it means the payment was declined by PayPal, for business reasons. It is a normal decline message that can happen al the time if PayPal won't process a payment.

If the same code was live and a real customer tried to use it, the expectation is it generally wouldn't be declined like that without reason.

So, when the time comes that you really need a live test, put your code on a public webserver and maybe have a friend or coworker in a remote location test it.